# Solution of system of equations in prime fields

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, systems-of-equations

In 'Algebra', Artin writes that the system of equation:

$$8x+3y = 3$$
$$2x+6y = -1$$

have no solutions in $\mathbb{F}_2$ and $\mathbb{F}_3$ as the determinant (of the coefficient matrix) evaluates to $42$ which is equal to $0$ (mod $2$, $3$ and $7$).

However he mentions that there happens to be a solution $(3, 0)$ in $\mathbb{F}_7$ though the determinant is zero modulo $7$. However this solution is not evident from the non-zero determinant (invertible matrix) rule we generally look at to determine whether solutions exist or not.

Should we always reduce the coefficient matrix elements (modulus $p$) before evaluating value of determinant to check if  a solution exists in $\mathbb{F}_p$? Is there a better way to check for existence of solutions in prime fields?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is evident from the matrix. in the field $Z/7Z,$ the system is
$$ x+3y = 3, $$
$$ 2x+6y = 6.      $$

Solutions are $(3,0), \; \; $  $(0,1), \; \; $  $(4,2), \; \; $   $(1,3), \; \; $   $(5,4), \; \; $  $(2,5), \; \; $  $(6,6). \; \; $

Comment: That much I guessed. Artin doesn't really explicitly mention the solution. I think a corollary he states before created the confusion.

"$AX = B$ has a unique solution in $\mathbb{F}_p$ if $det A \neq 0$"

Thanks anyway.

Comment: @slothc, have you had a course in linear algebra?

Comment: Self-studying through Artin and Herstein.

Comment: @slothc, given your comments, you would have an easier time with a full course in linear algebra first, just over the reals (and sometimes complex numbers).

Comment: I would. Using Axler for that. Tho' I am pretty sure I was just being stupid about this particular question. The solution set is just the coset $X_0 + N$ where $X_0$ is any one solution (say $(3, 0) $) and N is the space of solutions of  $AX = 0$. (or the nullspace), isn't it?

Comment: @slothc, you are getting there. Over the fields mentioned, the matrix has rank one. On the one hand, given one solution (with the nonzero target on the right hand side) the difference of any two solutions is in the kernel. That's what you wrote so far. The other viewpoint is that the coefficient matrix takes the full vector space to a one-dimensional subspace, the image, and the target on the right hand side may or may not be in that.  Let's use different letters, the image made up of all $(x+3y,2x+6y)$ is precisely all those pairs $(u,v)$ with $v \equiv 2u \pmod 7.$

Comment: Things come together much better now. Thanks again.